# Why does BLE advertising interval need to be multiple of 0.625msec?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ads

The BT Core Spec specifies that the BLE advertising interval has to be multiple of 0.625 msec. In addition to the advertising interval, there is an additional 0-10msec advertising delay to avoid collisions. My questions are:

- why the 0.625 msec specification especially that you add 0-10msec random delay?
- what happens if the advertising interval was not a multiple of 0.625msec? What are the consequences?

Thanks for your time and help.

I haven’t tried any other interval yet. Still at design phase.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth Classic uses a time slotted scheme of 0.625 ms per slot. I guess the 0.625 ms multiple in BLE is there so that it can easily be combined with Bluetooth Classic, i.e. Bluetooth Classic timing and BLE scheduling implementation in the same device can use the same underlying clock which works with a 0.625 ms time base. You also need some kind of base when instructing the controller over HCI what interval you want to set. 0.625 ms per step apparently was decided as a good step.

There are no consequences if an actual implementation does not use a multiple of 0.625 ms. You usually have clocks drifting as well as the random added value anyway so no one will notice.

The random delay is to avoid chances of getting collisions, in case two advertisers send overlapping events. It is possible to "round" a generated random value to the nearest 0.625 ms step, if it makes it sense for the implementation, i.e. when the implementation uses a base of 0.625 for its timings anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Emil for your reply. 
I understand that the timing could be “off” due to drifts and delays hence adhering to the 0.625msec rate is not crucial. 

SoI am thinking out loud here. 
How about the scanner side? Do BLE scanners set their scanning windows/intervals on the basis that the advertiser is transmitting at a specific rate? These are asynchronous events, by they both assume a 0.625msec base rate for advertisements. 
I think the answer is “it shouldn’t matter” but I just want to double check with someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I understand that some members of the Stack Overflow community might consider this question inappropriate because of the lack of software reference, but on the other hand, the Bluetooth SIG lists Stack Overflow itself as the [main developer community](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/build/developer-forum/). So I think this question fits the topic in a way.

The Bluetooth LE radio is a half-duplex device that can transmit and/or receive, but not both at the same time. The Time Division Duplex (TDD) scheme used makes it appear to be a full-duplex connection. In addition, the use of a precisely defined timing allows the receivers to be activated only at precisely defined times, resulting in significant energy savings.
If a device doesn't meet the timing requirements, functions such as [Active Scan](https://support.digitalmatter.com/support/solutions/articles/16000100684-active-vs-passive-bluetooth-scanning) won't work.

The random delay of 0-10 msec allows different devices to span different networks, adhering to the required timings without interfering with the networks of other devices.

I think the [Bluetooth Low Energy (LE) Primer](https://www.bluetooth.com/de/blog/introducing-the-bluetooth-low-energy-primer/)is a good introduction to this technology.

Comment: I don't really see how your answer is relevant for the question. TDD is for Bluetooth classic, not for BLE advertising. "allows devices to span different networks" - this makes no sense for BLE advertising.

Comment: @Emil I have a different opinion.  If you look at the "BLUETOOTH CORE SPECIFICATION Version 5.4 | Vol 6, Part A, 1 SCOPE" for example, you will find the following quote: "A Time Division Duplex (TDD) scheme is used on all PHYs. The specification
defines the requirements for a Bluetooth radio for the Low Energy radio."

Comment: Regarding the "allows different devices to span different networks" I also recommend  reading the BLUETOOTH CORE SPECIFICATION Version 5.4 | Vol 1, Part A, 3.3.2.2.2 Characteristics: "The advertising events occur at regular intervals which are slightly modified with a random delay to aid in interference avoidance." and since every advertising message is the necessary starting point of a connection, I stick to my formulation.

Comment: Ok I stand corrected regarding TDD that they use the same formulation in BLE. But how does it relate to the 0.625 ms value and advertisement intervals and the random delay? And why is it important in this question that advertisements are used to create connections? The first connection event packet can have any offset (controlled by the central) from the advertising packet that created the connection.